# Insert a gear into a turntable?

Tags: technic, building, gears, disassembly

Is there a way to insert a [24 tooth gear](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3648&name=Technic,%20Gear%2024%20Tooth%20(2nd%20Version%20-%201%20Axle%20Hole)&category=%5BTechnic,%20Gear%5D#T=C) into a turntable of [the 48452cx1 type](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48452cx1#T=C)?

[image]  -->  [image]

Is there any model to feature any tooth gear (even smaller) used inside this turntable?

This specific combination leads me to the conclusion that can not do this unless the turntable is disassembled or the 24 tooth gear modified.

Is there any method known to disassemble 48452cx1 without damaging it?

Comment: I distinctively recall having placed such 24 tooth gear in such turntable and being pleased how perfectly it fitted, perhaps you had a slightly different mold of the 24 tooth gear... I do agree with Alex that there is not much use for placing a 24 tooth gear inside the center of such turntable...

Comment: Probably you have inserted it when it was not assembled yet. The studs are preventing it.

Comment: You are correct, just tried, will post picture as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed I had to disassemble it (which went without much effort) but the 24 tooth fits fine:

[image]

It can slip up or down for about half a stud but is stuck otherwise.

Comment: This is the expected mount, but how did you disassemble it without damaging it?

Comment: I could wiggle it enough until I could put a screwdriver under the lid and just forced it. I have sufficient of these turntables that I could risk one, but wouldn't advise doing this if you consider your turntables as very precious.

Comment: Any chance you took a picture of the inside workings of it? That might help with preparing for gentle disassembly.

Comment: Bricklink has a picture of the light grey base part... there's a recess round te inner cilinder where the black part just clips... On second thought, the clips on the black part are quite large (about a quarter of the circle arc each) and seem quite sturdy. So opening it by simply prying it open with a sharp tool betweel black and grey part is probably reasonably safe

Answer (score 7):

I'm struggling to understand why would there be a need to insert 24T gear inside turntable gear. If you need rigid connection - it is best to use existing attachment points for you assembly.

Internal gearing works with 8T gears. 3 of them could be used in line to have planetary gearing (actually, two is enough, but to make thing a little more rigid 3 are needed). I've seen fair share of such solution being used by Truck Trial MOC's and some Crawlers within their wheel hubs to increase the torque at the wheels. Here's an [example](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-54129/doerma/planetary-gear-hub/) of one such hub.

Comment: A 16T gear should work as well.  Probably just 1 though?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman In terms of size both 16T as well as 12T, will fit. However, you would need to play around a little to attach them properly. For example, 16T has an offset of half a stud. 12T will be a little more trickier to attach inside turntable gear.

Comment: That too - I wasn't aware that 12T was a thing (until I looked it up just now), don't think I've ever seen one.